# jQuery change text of a div if it's sibling contains a certain string of text

Tags: jquery, each

So I know how to do something like this, but I have multiple elements that my .each(function() is running on, I need to make sure only .modules that contain spans with "Open 24 hours" trigger the change of the div to "ALWAYS OPEN" and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong

```
if (thisTimeSet === 'Open 24 hours'){ 
    $(this).siblings("div").text("ALWAYS OPEN"); }
```

Full working demo of the app: http://jsfiddle.net/DxaV7/
I have a ton of comments because I am pretty new to js and I need to walk myself though what I am doing (newb)

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: you could also just check if(thisTimeSet.indexOf('Open 24 hours') > 0) but I think your selector within is wrong. I don't have the time to drill it down for you, but this can help get you pointed in the right area

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:-

Problem here is you have many spans with the same text so your `===` doesn't match. I am just using indexOf to find the instance of atlease one which would mean that it is "Always Open"

```
if (thisTimeSet.indexOf('Open 24 hours') > -1) {
        $(this).find('.openOrNot').text("ALWAYS OPEN");
}
```

Another thing to add is you are not looking at siblings of `.module` instead its child `.openOrNot`. So you need to use find to descend down instead of looking at the peers using `siblings`.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RLuvt/)

Edit:-
As per your comment you can select spans that are only visible

`var thisTimeSet = $(this).children("span:visible").text();`

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7mDr/)

Comment: Hey, great I think this is really close! but because in my demo locations, QDoba has some days(fri + sat) with "Open 24 Hours" it is throwing the "ALWAYS OPEN" flag even today, when they are not open 24 hours, do you have any ideas to fix this? There are 6 invisible spans with values in each box, and one visible one I want the statement that checks if the text is equal to "Open 24 hours" to only test the visible span for each .module if that makes sense

Comment: Updated the answer see if that s what you were looking for.

Comment: Awesome, this is perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (thisTimeSet === 'Open 24 hours'){ 
    $(this).siblings("div:contains('ALWAYS OPEN')"); }
```

Comment: [I'm just going to leave this here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-contains-selector-vs-indexof)